# How can return reference to Dictionary from a method as readonly?

Tags: c#

I want to let users iterate through my dictionary without modifying it.

I considertwo solutions:

1.ReadOnlyDictionary -- is there an implementation of that available?

2.Copy the entire dictionary -- what is the most efficient way to copy it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to implement your own collection that is a wrapper around a Dictionary, something along the lines of:

```
public class ReadOnlyDictionary<T, U>
{
    private IDictionary<T, U> BackingStore;

    public ReadOnlyDictionary<T, U>(IDictionary<T, U> baseDictionary) {
        this.BackingStore = baseDictionary;
    }

    public U this[T index] { get { return BackingStore[index]; } }

    // provide whatever other methods and/or interfaces you need
}
```

Comment: you should consider makeing your ReadOnlyDictionary inherit IDictinary.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that your values will not be read only with the solutions provided for wrapping a Dictionary with only a property getter; For example:

```
ReadOnlyDictionary<int, Employee> readOnlyDict = GetDictionaryHoweverYouLike();
ReadOnlyDictionary[5].EmployeeName = "Ooops"
```

To do that you will also need to wrap your values in a read only wrapper class.

Comment: It depends how expensive your values are to copy

Answer (score 2):

Here's a implementation that I use for all those who need a ready to got snippet. As mentioned before this will only make the Dictionary readonly but not the objects within it!

```
/// <summary>
/// Read only wrapper for generics based dictionary.
/// Only provides lookup retrieval abilities.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
public class DictionaryReadOnly<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    #region Private Members

    private IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _item;
    private bool _throwOnWritableAction = false;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor requiring the generic dictionary being wrapped.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    public DictionaryReadOnly(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> items)
    {
        _throwOnWritableAction = true;
        _item = items;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor requiring the generic dictionary being wrapped.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    public DictionaryReadOnly(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> items, bool throwOnWritableAction)
    {            
        _throwOnWritableAction = throwOnWritableAction;
        _item = items;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of items in the dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _item.Count; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if the underlying collection contains the key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _item.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value associated with the key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return _item[key]; }
        set
        {
            CheckAndThrow("Set");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return keys.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return _item.Keys; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not-supported.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        CheckAndThrow("Add");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not-supported.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        CheckAndThrow("Remove");
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Try to get the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        value = default(TValue);

        if (_item.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            value = _item[key];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the values.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { return _item.Values; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Not-supported.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        CheckAndThrow("Add");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not-Supported.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        CheckAndThrow("Clear");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine whether key value pair is in dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return _item.Contains(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copy items to the array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array"></param>
    /// <param name="arrayIndex"></param>
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this._item.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicate read-only
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Non-supported action.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        CheckAndThrow("Remove");
        return false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the enumerator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _item.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the enumerator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _item.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Check and thrown based on flag.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    void CheckAndThrow(string action)
    {
        if (_throwOnWritableAction)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not perform action : " + action + " on this read-only collection.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to provide enumeration, you could expose it as [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) of the Key/Value pair type. However, this obviously restricts some of the read-only tasks that can be performed.

Another option is to write a new class, derived from [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) that provides read-only access by mapping those calls through to your real, wrapped dictionary, and throwing exceptions on any modifying calls like `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

Expose an enumeration(IEnumerable).

*Edit:* Example:

```
class A : IEnumerable<B>
{
  ...
  public IEnumerator<B> GetEnumerator ( )
  {
    return _dictionary.GetEnumerator ( );
  }
  private Dictionary<B> _dictionary;
}
```